# How to display data from map method only 5 item

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, object

I have a external Json file that displays data within the site. And I need to limit the display to only 5.

```js
    const displayCharacters = (characters) => {
          characters.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.rate - b.rate;
          });
          characters.sort((a, b) => b.rate - a.rate);
        
          characters.forEach(() => {
            const htmlString = characters
              .map((character) => {
                return `
                          <div class="col-6 my-2" onClick="addToCart(${character.id} )"></div>
                            <div class="menu card my-3" style="width: 120px">
                              <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="menu-name">${character.nama}</h5>
                                <p> ${character.harga}</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                  `;
              })
              .join('') ;
            charactersList.innerHTML = htmlString;
          });
        };
        
        loadCharacters();
```

help me guys

Comment: JSON is a text format and irrelevant here. `characters` is an *Array*, and getting the first five elements can be done using [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JS [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method to slice the array before using the map method.

```js
    const displayCharacters = (characters) => {
          characters.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.rate - b.rate;
          });
          characters.sort((a, b) => b.rate - a.rate);
        
          characters.forEach(() => {
            const htmlString = characters
              .slice(0, 5)
              .map((character) => {
                return `
                          <div class="col-6 my-2" onClick="addToCart(${character.id} )"></div>
                            <div class="menu card my-3" style="width: 120px">
                              <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="menu-name">${character.nama}</h5>
                                <p> ${character.harga}</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                  `;
              })
              .join('') ;
            charactersList.innerHTML = htmlString;
          });
        };
        
        loadCharacters();
```

Answer (score 0):

[`console.dir(object,{depth:5})`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_dir_obj_options)

At least in node.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use index in foreach and check if index is less then or equal to 5

```
        const displayCharacters = (characters) => {
                          characters.sort((a, b) => {
                            return a.rate - b.rate;
                          });
                          characters.sort((a, b) => b.rate - a.rate);
                        
                          characters.forEach(funtion(data,index) { //Here you will take now index so on index based you can check data limit
                            const htmlString = characters
                              .map((character) => {
                            if(index=<5){ //it will run untill index is less then and equal to 5
                                return 
                                          <div class="col-6 my-2" onClick="addToCart(${data.id} )"></div>
                                            <div class="menu card my-3" style="width: 120px">
                                              <div class="card-body">
                                                <h5 class="menu-name">${data.nama}</h5>
                                                <p> ${data.harga}</p>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                  `;
 }
                              })
                              .join('') ;
                            charactersList.innerHTML = htmlString;
    
                          });
           
                        };
                        
                        loadCharacters();
```

Comment: If it work please accept and upvote this answer